# How can I make a multipart/form-data POST request using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Does anybody know that how to make a multipart/form-data in javascript? Is there any plugin support for it?

I'm using REST api to submit form in JSON, now I have to upload file.

Comment: dont downvote me because you are to lazy to use google. your answer has been asked multiple times on stackoverflow. we will not do your work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got HTML5 FormData to upload files via Ajax request .... :)

For reference : [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)